# Participe présent ou gérondif?

Tags: participe-présent

Qu´est-ce qui est correct,

> En croyant qu'il serait là, je n'ai pas pris mes clés.

ou

> Croyant il serait là, je n'ai pas pris mes clés."

?

Il est difficile de distinguer entre participe présent et gérondif...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La première phrase n'est pas très vraisemblable car elle impliquerait que les deux événements n'ont pas de lien autre que leur simultanéité alors que la deuxième proposition (je n'ai pas pris mes clés) est clairement une conséquence de la première (il serait là).

Si on inverse les propositions, la phrase devient idiomatique et le gérondif peut laisser sous-entendre une relation de causalité :

> je n'ai pas pris mes clés en croyant qu'il serait là.

ou :

> je n'ai pas pris mes clés en croyant qu'il allait être là.

La simultanéité simple, sans lien, est visible dans une phrase comme :

> En partant de chez moi, je n'ai pas pris mes clés.

La deuxième phrase est correcte si on y ajoute *que*:

> Croyant **qu**'il serait là, je n'ai pas pris mes clés.

Qui signifie:

> Je croyais qu'il serait là donc je n'ai pas pris mes clés.

> Je n'ai pas pris mes clés parce que je croyais qu'il serait là.

Answer (score 0):

**I**

On peut  lire ceci dans LBU 14ième edition, p. 1478, R2, § 1134.

> On dit souvent, par exemple, que le gérondif marque ici **le temps**, là **la cause**, ailleurs encore **l'opposition** ou **la condition**, tout cela sans changer de forme. Cela prouve que le gérondif ne suffit pas à indiquer ces différentes valeurs et donc qu'il n'en indique en soi aucune. C'est le contexte, la situation qui font établir entre les faits une relation logique qui n'est pas exprimée grammaticalement.

Le gérondif peut être utilisé pour exprimer la cause, ce que confirme cette [référence](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-83422.php) (Français Facile). La cause pour ne pas prendre les clés c'est  d'avoir cru qu'il était là, ou, en d'autres termes, la conséquence d'avoir cru qu'il était là est de ne pas avoir  pris les clés.   La première phrase est correcte parce que le contexte marque clairement qu'il y a une relation de cause à effet entre ce qui est cru et le fait de ne pas prendre les clés.

Par exemple, aucun sens ne peut être donné à la phrase suivante ; du point de vue sémantique c'est du non-sens et on peut dire qu'elle n'est pas correcte.

- En croyant que j'étais presque arrivé je suis tombé et je me suis blessé au genou.

La phrase aurait aussi pu être formulée comme suit, ce qui est plus courant mais pas « plus correct ».

- Je n'ai pas pris mes clés  en croyant qu'il serait là.

On trouve des exemples de cette sorte dans la littérature ; quelques uns suivent.

([réf. 1, 2006](https://books.google.fr/books?id=8VBbp6z2jJgC&pg=PA264&dq=%22en+voyant+qu%27il%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBvO-zt7rtAhUQrxoKHVQHCTsQ6AEwAHoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22en%20voyant%20qu%27il%22&f=false)) Bohort chargea alors vers le groupe des chevaliers, en disant : – En garde, je vous défie ! **En voyant qu'il était tout seul à les défier**, les chevaliers furent ébahis et, n'était la crainte du déshonneur, ils seraient tombés à trois sur lui.
(*Les chevaliers furent ébahis **parce que** ils virent que Bohort était tout seul ; le fait de voir que Bohort était tout seul **est la cause** (le pourquoi) de leur ébahissement.*)

([réf. 2, 2017](https://books.google.fr/books?id=3CxADwAAQBAJ&pg=PT242&dq=%22en+comprenant+qu%27il%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjl3LzWubrtAhU5DWMBHWbuBREQ6AEwAHoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22en%20comprenant%20qu%27il%22&f=false)) Je me sens honteuse **en comprenant qu'il me laisse tomber**. – À moins que tu ne préfères finir de regarder.
(***Parce qu**'elle comprend qu'il la laisse tomber elle se sent honteuse ; la **cause** (le pourquoi) de sa honte **est** qu'elle comprend qu'il la laisse tomber.*)

([réf. 3, 2010](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Eds-BorClGQC&pg=PT128&dq=%22en+comprenant+qu%27il%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjl3LzWubrtAhU5DWMBHWbuBREQ6AEwAnoECAQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22en%20comprenant%20qu%27il%22&f=false))  – Bon sang, grogna Brody **en comprenant qu'il venait sans doute de la perdre**.
(***Parce qu**'il comprit qu'il venait  de la perdre Brody grogna « Bon sang » ; comprendre qu'il venait de la perdre **est la cause** (le pourquoi) de l'exclamation.*)

([réf. 4, 2012](https://books.google.fr/books?id=yfFm1HFBLyIC&pg=PT29&dq=%22en+comprenant+qu%27il%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjl3LzWubrtAhU5DWMBHWbuBREQ6AEwBHoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=%22en%20comprenant%20qu%27il%22&f=false)) Mais le choc en le voyant, **en comprenant qu'il avait manqué huit ans de son existence**, avait été d'une violence inouïe. (*Comprendre qu'il avait manqué huit ans de son existence **est la cause** du choc d'une violence inouï.*)

**II**

La seconde phrase est aussi correcte et exprime la même chose (mis à part qu'il faut ajouter la conjonction « que » : « Croyant qu'il serait… »).  Ceci est vrai parce le participe présent peut être utilisé pour exprimer la cause ([Français Facile](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-83422.php)). Cependant, ainsi que le mentionne la référence, cette façon d'exprimer la cause relève de la langue formelle et donc dans le parler quotidien on utilisera plutôt la première phrase.